# How do I check two or more conditions in one <c:if>?

Tags: jstl, el

How do I check two conditions in one `<c:if>`? I tried this, but it raises an error:

```
<c:if test="${ISAJAX == 0} && ${ISDATE == 0}">
```

Answer (score 166, accepted):

This look like a duplicate of [JSTL conditional check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219730/jstl-conditinal-check).

The error is having the `&&` outside the expression. Instead use

```
<c:if test="${ISAJAX == 0 && ISDATE == 0}">
```

Answer (score 36):

If you are using JSP 2.0 and above It will come with the [EL support](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html): 
so that you can write in plain english and use `and` with `empty` operators to write your test:

```
<c:if test="${(empty object_1.attribute_A) and (empty object_2.attribute_B)}">
```

Answer (score 20):

**Recommendation:**

when you have more than one condition with `and` and `or` is better separate with `()` to avoid verification problems

```
<c:if test="${(not validID) and (addressIso == 'US' or addressIso == 'BR')}">
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case somebody needs to check the condition from session.Usage of `or`

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope['roleid'] == 1 || sessionScope['roleid'] == 4}">
```