# How to use 2 conditions in a c:if?

Tags: jsp

I want to use 2 conditions in a `<c:if>` but i don't know if it is possible.

For example:

```
<c:if test="${(a.cost == b.cost) and (a.price == b.price)}" />
   Some code...
</c:if>
```

Comment: Looks fine. What's the problem?

Comment: Yes it works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355787/how-do-i-check-two-conditions-in-one-cif

Comment: Thank you all, somehow the problem was with eclipse. The code works great.

Answer (score 0):

Use && instead of `and`

```
<c:if test="${(a.cost == b.cost) && (a.price == b.price)}" />
   Some code...
</c:if>
```

Comment: Both 'and' and '&&' work. @LeosLiterak No, it is not a Java expression, it is an EL expression.

Comment: Thank you all, somehow the problem was with eclipse. The code works great.