# if else in jstl tags within jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp, session, jstl

```
<div align="right">
     <b> Connected:</b> <%=(String)session.getAttribute("CONNECTION_DBNAME")%>
     </div>
```

- I have the above code in jsp page
- Initially the the session CONNECTION_DBNAME has no value.
- When CONNECTION_DBNAME is null, i need to display not connected
- When CONNECTION_DBNAME has value, the some value gets printed.
- I know it can be achieved by using if else with condition, but i don't know how to use if else within jstl tag.

Comment: numerous duplicates that provide the answer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587397/how-to-use-if-else-option-in-jstl and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219267/if-else-in-jstl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div align="right">
     <b> Connected:</b> <%=(session.getAttribute("CONNECTION_DBNAME")!=null)?(String)session.getAttribute("CONNECTION_DBNAME"): "not connected"%>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.CONNECTION_DBNAME!= null}"> 
 Connected:${sessionScope.CONNECTION_DBNAME}
</c:if>
<c:if test="${sessionScope.CONNECTION_DBNAME== null}"> 
 NOT CONNECTED
</c:if>


  or 


<c:choose>
 <c:when test="${sessionScope.CONNECTION_DBNAME != null}">
   Connected:${sessionScope.CONNECTION_DBNAME}
 </c:when>  
 <c:otherwise>
  NOT CONNECTED
 </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: the thread title said something about jstl, so i would consider this the correct answer instead of the scriptlet solution above ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing as [@PSR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/937892/psr) recommended, just written a bit smaller, using a [ternary](/questions/tagged/ternary) expression, like this:

```
${empty sessionScope.CONNECTION_DBNAME ? 'NOT CONNECTED' : 'Connected' + sessionScope.CONNECTION_DBNAME }
```

or the reverse; check `not empty` and swap the position of the two results..

```
${not empty sessionScope.CONNECTION_DBNAME ? 'Connected' + sessionScope.CONNECTION_DBNAME : 'NOT CONNECTED'}
```