# c:if test condition actually regular expression?

Tags: jstl

I try to use condition

```
<c:when test="${game.duration!='0:00'}">
...show rows
...
```

The duration here is String, and condition should be true when the String does not match 0:00. This isn't working however! When I put

```
<c:when test="${game.duration=='0:00'}">
 ... show rows
```

Rows are hidden, even if the duration value would be etc. 5:45. Is condition actually regular expression? How to fix this?

Comment: Try <c:when test="${game.duration eq '0:00'}">. Maybe it should work. Or test your duration in back-end part, is it really equal?

Comment: Tried that/ne, same problem. Value is String coming from database.

Comment: Does your otherwise condition trigger or what's happening? You could try jstl functions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219267/how-do-i-do-the-equivalent-of-a-java-if-else-block-using-jstl#answer-6219300  or here better http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/J2EE/JSP/Q_21622213.html